Unable to render OpenGL commands in a GLArea widget using gi-gtk
I'm trying to port a gtk2hs program to gi-gtk and I want to render some OpenGL command in a GLArea inside a small Gtk gui.
I tried this program but it doesn't work although the "render" signal is correctly emitted (the putStrLn function print "onGLAreaRender" in the shell.
import qualified Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL as GL 
import GI.Gtk
import qualified GI.Gtk.Functions as Gtk

main :: IO ()
main= do
    Gtk.init Nothing
    window <- windowNew WindowTypeToplevel
    canvas <- gLAreaNew
    containerAdd window canvas
    gLAreaSetAutoRender canvas True
    onGLAreaRender canvas $ \_ -> do
                  GL.clearColor GL.$= (GL.Color4 0.3 0 0 1)
                  GL.clear [GL.ColorBuffer]
                  GL.loadIdentity
                  let points = concatMap (\y -> map (\x -> (x,y,0)) [-0.5::Float,-0.4..0.5]) [-0.5,-0.4..0.5]
                  renderPoints points
                  GL.flush
                  putStrLn "onGLAreaRender"
                  return True
    widgetShowAll window 
    onWidgetDestroy window mainQuit
    Gtk.main
    return ()

makeVertexes = mapM_ (\(x,y,z) -> GL.vertex $ GL.Vertex3 x y z)

renderPoints ps = GL.renderPrimitive GL.Points $ makeVertexes ps

The Gtk window appear, the clearColor command seams to work (the windows background isn't black) but nothing else is drawn inside.

I'm very disappointed because I made a small test with GLUT which work correctly
import Graphics.UI.GLUT
import Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL

main = do
    getArgsAndInitialize
    createAWindow "test points"
    mainLoop

createAWindow windowName = do
   createWindow windowName
   displayCallback $= display

display = do
         clearColor $= (Color4 0.3 0 0 1)
         clear [ColorBuffer]
         loadIdentity
         let points = concatMap (\y -> map (\x -> (x,y,0)) [-0.5::GLfloat,-0.4..0.5]) [-0.5,-0.4..0.5]
         renderPoints points
         flush

makeVertexes = mapM_ (\(x,y,z) -> vertex $ Vertex3 x y z)

renderPoints ps = renderPrimitive Points $ makeVertexes ps


I suspect a GLArea or OpenGL initialization problem in my gi-gtk gui, but I can't figure out which.
Do you know what I'm doing wrong in my Gtk program ?
Do you have an example of a working gi-gtk program using a GLArea ?
